# Getting Error for package name in netbeans

Tags: java, jsp

I am using one .java file and i have given a package name as **com.onlinmebank** but netbeans displaying error at this package declaration line as Incorrect Package.

Following is the package declaration code.

```
package com.onlinebank;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public  class BankCommons{

//All Code Here
}
```

Can Anybody tell me why i am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All Java keywords are lower-case!**

So, this should work:

```
package com.onlinebank;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class BankCommons {
    //All Code Here
}
```

And keep in mind, that the file BankCommons.java must be placed in the directory *com/onlinebank*.

Comment: actually all was in small letter by mistake it was printed in caps

Comment: Then I assume, your source code file (BankCommons.java) is placed in a wrong directory.

Comment: yes it was in com folder but not in onlinebank but now i have placed it correctly in com/onlinebank but still giving error

Comment: Maybe you moved the file outside of your IDE. Unfortunately, I am using Eclipse, not Netbeans. In Eclipse you must refresh a project, so that Eclipse is informed about structural changes in the project. Maybe this is the same in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

In package, p should be small not Package(no captial P).
Also in public class p should be small. Similarily for Import also.

**Important note** all java keywords are in lower cases

Comment: actually all was in small letter by mistake it was printed in caps

Comment: @Audy first of all you have to place your java code in com/onlinebank folder.